# Order of convergence

Tags: numerical-methods

How can find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, such that 
$x_{n+1}=\alpha x_n\left(3-\dfrac{x_n^2}{a}\right)+\beta x_n\left(1+\dfrac{a}{x_n^2}\right)$ has $3^{\text{rd}}$ order convergence to $\sqrt a$ ?

1. $\alpha=\dfrac{3}{8}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{1}{8}$
2. $\alpha=\dfrac{1}{8}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{3}{8}$
3. $\alpha=\dfrac{2}{8}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{2}{8}$
4. $\alpha=\dfrac{1}{4}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{3}{4}$

Comment: What did you try? Context?

Comment: $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ is converges if absolute value of f'(x)<1

Comment: But you need to find $3^{rd}$ order of convergence. Hence you have to prove that $\frac{|x_{k+1}-\sqrt{a}|}{(x_k-\sqrt{a})^3}$ converges

Comment: which of the following is possible (1) $\alpha=\frac{3}{8}$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{8}$

(2) $\alpha=\frac{1}{8}$ and $\beta=\frac{3}{8}$

(3) $\alpha=\frac{2}{8}$ and $\beta=\frac{2}{8}$

(4) $\alpha=\frac{1}{8}$ and $\beta=\frac{3}{8}$

Comment: Why $(2)$ and $(4)$ are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Set $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)=\alpha x_n(3-\frac{x_n^2}{a})+\beta x_n(1+\frac{a^2}{x_n^2})$ and denote $z=\sqrt{a}$. Replace $x_n$ by $x$.

Using Taylor's development we find:

$$f(x)=f(z)+f'(z)(x-z)+\frac{f''(z)}{2}(x-z)^2+\frac{f'''(z)}{6}(x-z)^3+\frac{f''''(\xi)}{24}(x-z)^4$$

for some $\xi\in(x,z)$. Since $f(z)=z$ and dividing the previous equation by $|x-z|^3$ we have:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(z)}{|x-z|^3}=\frac{f'(z)}{|x-z|^2}+\frac{f''(z)}{2|x-z|}+\frac{f'''(z)}{6}+\frac{f''''(\xi)}{24}|x-z|$$

So in order to converge to the $3^{rd}$ order we have to impose both $f'(z)=0$ and $f''(z)=0$. This give raise to the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\beta(1-a)&=0\\
-3\alpha+\beta&=0
\end{align}
$$

and hence

$$
\begin{align}
\beta(1-a)&=0\\
\beta&=3\alpha&
\end{align}
$$

Looking at the proposed solutions we have to choose $\color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{(2)}}}$

Remark:
solution $(4)$ seems to be a duplicate of $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, nice explanation